# Determine if the set $P$ is a vector space or not

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Consider the set
\begin{equation*}
    P=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3 : \mathbf{x}=\lambda_1\mathbf{v}_1+\lambda_2\mathbf{v}_2 \ \ \text{for} \ \ 0\leq\lambda_1\leq 1, 0\leq\lambda_2\leq 1\},
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2\in\mathbb{R}^3$. I am trying to determine if this set is a vector space.

**Attempt**

Intuitively $P$ is not a vector space since geometrically it represents a parallelogram. Hence an appropriately scaled vector should not belong to this set, in which case $P$ would not be closed under scalar multiplication. However I am having difficulty formulating a proof.

Let $$\mathbf{v_1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \mathbf{v_2}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Hence $$\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{v_1}+\mathbf{v_2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\in P,$$
where $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$. I cannot think of a counterexample such that $\mu\mathbf{a}\notin P$ for $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, since $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ are *arbitrary*.  For instance, $10\mathbf{a}\in P$ since we can 'make' this vector by taking $$\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2=1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \mathbf{v}_2=\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 10 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: More simply,  if $\vec v_1, \vec v_2$ are independent, then $-\vec v_1\not \in P$ (though $\vec v_1$ is). If they are dependent, you'll need a separate argument (which is not difficult)

Comment: In your case, $10(v_1+v_2)=v_2$, so $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent. But then $v_2=-10v_1/9$, and $P$ still does not contain all multiples of $v_1$.

Comment: In your proof, you are taking a $v_1,v_2$, and then changing the definition of $v_2$. It would help to think of them as fixed, and explore. In your example, you cannot "make" a vector, as you have already fixed your space. You are on the right track, but need to generalise, rather than using specific vectors.

Comment: Use the fact that the norm on $P$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbf v_1$ an $\mathbf v_2$ are independent. If $P$ is a vector space, then clearly $\mathbf x=(0*\mathbf v_1) + (1*\mathbf v_2) = \mathbf v_2\in P$. But since $P$ is a vector space, $-\mathbf v_2 \in P$. This implies $\lambda_2 = -1$, a contradiction.

If $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$ are dependent, then WLOG let $\mathbf v_1$ = $k\mathbf v_2$. Thus, $\mathbf x = \lambda_1 k \mathbf v_2 + \lambda_2 \mathbf v_2 \in P$. Setting $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 = 1$, we get $(k+1)\mathbf v_2 \in P$. Since $P$ is a vector space, $(k+2)\mathbf v_2 \in P$. But, $(k+2)\mathbf v_2 = \lambda_1 \mathbf v_1 + (\lambda_2 + 1)\mathbf v_2$ with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 = 1$, a contradiction.

The only way this is a vector space is if $\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2 = \mathbf 0$, creating the $\{\mathbf 0\}$ vector space.